# How does Optimus heal himself in Age of extinction?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, age-of-extinction

In Age of extinction, in the scene where Optimus is on the road with Cade and Tessa (after they take refuge in the broken down gas station), he transforms into a shiny new Western Star 4900 Phantom truck just by 'scanning' a similar truck that was passing by. One should remember that Optimus was pretty beat up and in terrible condition when Cade found him initially.

So all it takes to fix a transformer is a vehicle nearby that it can 'scan' and transform into? Or is this just more Michael Bay crap?

My issue is not with the scan and transform part. Optimus was almost falling apart when Cade found him. He had bullet holes in him and he could barely stand up. Even if he did transform by scanning the truck, how did he repair himself?

Comment: Though not an answer: it's always safe to assume the latter. :)

Comment: Remember, Bumble Bee did the same basic thing (no scan, but transformed nonetheless ... who knows, he could have already scanned the vehicle he transformed into) in the first movie. There is precidence.

Comment: @Paulster2: He did scan a Camaro in the first movie.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander ... I guess I was too interested in Megan Fox licking her lips and didn't remember that part.

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/588/49.

Comment: It's interesting that you ask this question because at first I was like, well taking the fact that they can morph into whatever they want (they just happen to choose automobiles), they could easily morph into a non destroyed form. However, in the first movie when bumblebee was missing a leg or two, why couldn't he just regrow it? It might be relative to mass, since he lost mass he could not do so, but if optimus only had superficial damage, then he could morph it all out.

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/can-transformers-actually-die

Comment: Since Optimus Prime is an alien being capable of shape shifting and unlike a robot, he can absorb the particles from the surroundings to mimic/convert shape and color. What powers it is a cube shaped object in his core. Which can be called the matrix of leadership although the movies don't specify completely. Remember, he's a member of an alien bot race that can take on shapes and forms. Pretty cool isn't it.

Answer (score 3):

Optimus got that missile in his body which make him unable to do self-repair or morph to a better vehicle. However once Cade remove that, he can do it again. How can he morph to another and better vehicle? Well, they were call Transformer for god sake and they have **Sparks**, their source of life which allow them to do all those self repair, morphing, transforming etc.

Since movie one, all of the transformers got beaten, thrown, shot with missle etc, and they always return to their initial condition. They are made with this superb metal call **Transformium** and with the power of the Sparks inside them, they can morph to anything they want, by just scanning and imprinting animate object around them.

Comment: *"they can morph to anything they want"* -- can you provide examples for this?  Transformers are  biological beings. I do not remember any scene where an Autobot, primarily having land borne transformation, decides to scan a jet plane or a bird and  become air-borne suddenly.

Comment: _"they have Sparks, their source of life which allow them to do all those self repair, morphing, transforming"_ - actually, Sparks are more like a transformer's Soul, their ability to transform is possible thanks to **Transformation Cog** ;)  https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformation_cog

Answer (score 1):

Well, while *Optimus* certainly *"was pretty beatup and in terrible condition when Cade found him initially"*, you also have to keep in mind that *Cade* already repaired him quite a bit, up to a degree where *Optimus* didn't need his fellow transformers to repair him anymore. This is also evident from his rather agile and more or less fully functional behaviour during their escape from the farm.

So ***Optimus* already had been repaired up to normal standards by *Cade***. The rest of his rather rusty appearance was just part of his current appearance as this old truck model and not due to his previous "injuries". Whyever he had that appearance (most likely as disguise to evade the current anti-*Transformer* pogroms), he didn't see any need to uphold it anymore and switched to a more comfortable/modern appearance as soon as the possibility arose. In addition to that, the correlation between the *Transformers*' vehicle appearance and their "humanoid" appearance is not entirely clear anyway, as evident from [this related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/588/49).

So to sum up, **he didn't repair himself by scanning that vehicle but simply changed his appearance, as he already had been repaired to acceptable degrees by *Cade* earlier.**

Comment: Apart from that, I guess one could also just say *"Forget it Bobby, it's Transformers"*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In a bit of exposition in the first one, Scorponok's tail was said to be healing/regenerating (except for the bits hit by the sable? rounds). It could be that once reactivated, Optimus began to heal, but given the extent of damage it would have been quicker to be 'fixed'. As for his rusty appearance (except for bullet holes of course), my guess is it was just the form he had been using to evade the cia and not a direct result of damage.

Answer (score -1):

During the First movie, **this exact thing** happens with Bumblebee:

He scans another Camaro, and takes its likeness by doing so. It's such an integral aspect of the franchise, there is even a Toy of the Camero Mid-Scan. 
[image]

As Paulster *tried* to say above, there is absolutely a **Precedent** for this... ;)

Comment: John, I have added some more information to the question. The issue is not with the transformation but how he fixed himself.

Comment: What is the difference between what happened with Bumblebee and **what Optimus did?** Bumblebee was a battered old Camaro and 'fixed' himself into a newer model, without damage. Its the exact same principle. They both transform into something without damage: you're issue is the difference in perceived damage, why would you assume this is a factor in this process?

Comment: My problem is in the film Optimus clearly states he needs to get to his fellow Autobots so they can fix him up, and then after the fight with Cemetery Wind on Cade's farm 10 minutes later he scans the truck and oh boy, he's all better! He went from explicitly saying he needed help to repair himself, to literally doing it with a single scan of a shiny new truck.

Comment: Also if this was the case, they could just scan a nearby vehicle every time they are in a fight!

Comment: @MattD - I presumed that he was still damaged after scanning the new truck. And when they met up with the other Autobots they fixed him off screen. As you are right, he was damaged and needed Autobot help to fix him but this was never screened.

Comment: @MattD He said that before *Cade* stood in and repaired him. After all he already was better during the fight (before the scan).

Comment: No, no and no, transformers cant repair just scanning, their initial scan is just to have a camuflage, also keep in mind megatron couldnt repair himself in the later movies, he had to use small bots to do the task, yes they can heal but to a lesser degree so its a michael bay bs